# Como passar parâmetro para validação/tratamento na view RUBY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou com uma grande dúvida, aceito dicas se verem uma opção melhor para fazer oque estou querendo. Tenho um layout que linka para dois itens a mesma view>>

```
<ul class="nav nav-second-level">
  <li>
   <%= link_to backoffice_pedidos_path do %>
     Abertos
   <% end %>
  </li>
  <li>
    <%= link_to backoffice_pedidos_path do %>
      Finalizados
    <% end %>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Quero tratar na view o conteúdo do meu select, se ele clicar em ABERTOS, ele carrega a index com uma partial _abertos e caso ele clique em Finalizados ele carrega a index mas com uma outra partial _finalizados. Há alguma maneira de passar algum parametro no link_to para que na view eu possa tratar ele para mandar para a partial correta? Ou alguma dica de como possa ficar?

index>>

```
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Pedido</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Data/Hora </th>
                        <th>Produtos </th>                    
                        <th> </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody> 
                  <% if ??
                  <%= render partial: "backoffice/pedidos/abertos" %>
                  else ??
                  <%= render partial: "backoffice/pedidos/finalizados" %>
                  <% end %>
                </tbody>
```

**partial abertos>>**

```
           <% @pedidos_aguardando.each do |pedido| %>
        <tr> 
          <td><%=pedido.id%></td>
          <td><%=pedido.status%></td>
          <td><%=pedido.created_at%></td>
          <!--<th><%=pedido.produtos.first.produto %></th>-->
          <td><%=pedido.produtos.pluck (:produto)%></td>
          <td width="50px">
              <%= link_to edit_backoffice_pedido_path(pedido), class:"btn btn-primary btn-circle" do %>
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
              <% end %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
```

**Partials fechados**

```
           <% @pedidos_finalizados.each do |pedido| %>
        <tr> 
          <td><%=pedido.id%></td>
          <td><%=pedido.status%></td>
          <td><%=pedido.created_at%></td>
          <!--<th><%=pedido.produtos.first.produto %></th>-->
          <td><%=pedido.produtos.pluck (:produto)%></td>
          <td width="50px">
              <%= link_to edit_backoffice_pedido_path(pedido), class:"btn btn-primary btn-circle" do %>
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
              <% end %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
def index
@pedidos_aguardando = Pedido.waiting
@pedidos_finalizados = Pedido.ok
 end
```

**Model**

```
class Pedido < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :produtos

scope :waiting, -> { where(status: 1) }
scope :ok, -> { where(status: 2) }
end
```

Obrigado!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc coloca no link o parâmetro:

link_to backoffice_pedidos_path(tipo: 'abertos')

isso vai te dar no controller acesso a um params[:tipo]

coloque isso numa variável, lembrando de tratar o caso do primeiro load, onde este parâmetro estará vazio ex:

```
@tipo = params[:tipo] || 'abertos'
```

Use o nome das partials nos parametros, assim na view vc faz:

```
<%= render partial: "backoffice/pedidos/#{@tipo}" %>
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, tinha feito de outra forma, assim simplificou muito meu código, tinha passado um parametro FLAG, e tava tratando com IF na view. Dessa forma, tratando no controller fica bem melhor!! Valeu!